# TCP message not received more than 1 time

Tags: java, tcp, client

```
class SomeUI     
{ 
SocketMessageSender messageSender; 
// ensure that its initialized ... 
private void bSendMessageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            messageSender.sendMessage(jMessage.getText()); 
            jMessage.setText("");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TeKServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 
}
```

ERROR: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: bSendMessageActionPerformed

Comment: What does the server code do?

Comment: The server code works just fine because I tested it on PHP side too, the server takes incoming calls from the client and shows it in the server chat

Comment: None of this should be done in an actionPerformed method. They should not perform blocking operations.

Comment: so what do you suggest where should I make it, in main? Because if I make it in main I wouldn't be able to use String process = jMessage.getText(); and if I make it in run() my app will freeze due to the TCP connection(?)

Comment: Your question is related to your server code, and you are not prepared to show your server code ..?

Comment: actually the server side code is being done by someone else im working with and its on his computer now and its PAWN language for GTASA SAMP gaming. Trust me when I made a TCP client for this server on PHP it would send multiple strings to the server its just this java code that doesnt

Comment: Also, please read [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Writing short examples of code is preferred when posting to forums.

Comment: This seems to be a compilation error rather than anything to do with TCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you keep opening the socket and closing it on every button click. Create a class that allow you to keep the socket open for as long as your application run. The socket connection can be done when the application starts.You can try out the following class

```
public class SocketMessageSender
{
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private DataOutputStream dos;

    public SocketMessageSender(String host, int port)
    {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
    }

    // call when application starts
    public void initConnection() throws IOException
    {
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        Socket connection = new Socket(address, port);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    }

    //call from button click
    public void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException
    {
        if(dos != null)
        {
            dos.writeUTF(message);
            dos.flush();
        }
    }

    // call when application exits
    public void closeConnection() throws IOException
    {
        if(dos!= null)
        {
            dos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ...

Assume you have a class like

```
class SomeUI
{
   SocketMessageSender messageSender;
   // ensure that its initialized ...



 private void bSendMessageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    messageSender.sendMessage(jMessage.getText());
    jMessage.setText("");
 }
}
```

I think that the class signature should be something like this ....

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private SocketMessageSender messageSender;
    private Message jMessage = new Message();// This is just a temp class, replace this with your class

    public MyPanel()
    {
        messageSender = new SocketMessageSender("some host", 8080);
        try
        {
            messageSender.initConnection();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             Logger.getLogger(MyPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            messageSender.sendMessage(jMessage.getText()); 
            jMessage.setText("");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man thats exactly what I needed.. helped a lot. Also if you could please tell me how will the above code know when the button is clicked? I mean in sendMessage shall I add onClickListener ?

Comment: It gives me this error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: bSendMessageActionPerformed

Comment: can you share your source codenow , and the full class will be good .

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/8QFFM2ci If this codes look a bit confusing (because ive used jframe but in the code you'll see the initialization of the buttons and stuff which might make the code look a bit messy then please let me know ill try ogranise it all

Comment: I'm going for lunch now allow me 15 minutes I'll be right back to provide you everything you need to help me fix this :D

Comment: I need help with this problem please... Check my first post again I've updated it, it gives me this error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: bSendMessageActionPerformed

Comment: I have updated the reply, please check it out to see if it helps, let me know if you still face problems.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream and write object through sockets.
There are a lot of examples at java2s.com

Please mind that if you are writing same object multiple times, you will need to reset() stream before writing, and flush after it.

Comment: how so ? sorry I'm new to java and I'd like it if you could make an example code